# Is there a better way of transporting bagels to work?

Tags: food, moving, work

I take a bagel to work every day. I wrap it in a plastic bag, but this isn't great, it usually gets a bit squashed in my backpack.

Is there something that I could use to transport my bagel to work that will prevent this happening? It must be:

- Not much larger than the bagel - I don't want it rattling around, and there's not much spare room in my backpack
- Not smaller than the bagel - It mustn't squash it
- Have a hard exterior - To prevent squashing by other things in the bag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This one from Tupperware carries bagels. You can look for "bagel container" or similar terms to get more results on similar products. [Tupperware bagel container on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0049P1A6K)

A peek of what it looks like: 
[image]

Answer (score 13):

Carry them in one of the round boxes blank CD-roms come in sometimes.

[image: Blank cdroms]

Comment: More like 'inside the box' amirite :^)

Comment: Could this leech chemicals from the plastic into my food?

Comment: If you want something quick, dirty, and with a chance of poison in your food, get a lifehack. If you want something that has been tested, verified and produced to be safe for food, get something built for the purpose. =p

Comment: If I was concerned about chemicals, I would cut the "peg" from inside the container. Then, I'd keep my bagel wrapped in that baggie, and use the CD holder to prevent bagged-and-sealed bagel from getting squished.

Answer (score 1):

Tupperware and similar brands have a wide selection of plastic containers. You can probably find one the right size for a bagel.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever made a [book safe](http://www.instructables.com/id/Better-Book-Safe/?ALLSTEPS)? You can make a book safe and stow the bagel inside it; however, I would wrap the bagel in handiwrap or something before putting it in the book safe to avoid ink, paper fragments, or anything else from getting on to my bagel.